# How to call Java Swing in HTML

Tags: java, html, swing, applet

I'm trying to call my Java Swing code in html.

```html
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE> A Simple Program </TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

Here is the output of my program:
<embed src="JavaApplication3.class" WIDTH=1000 HEIGHT=1000>
</embed>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I tried applet tag and object tag too. Safari says " Missing Plugin " , chrome says " File Not Found ". `MyJavaSwing.class` and HTML are in the same folder and I tried all permutations and combinations.

I checked my safari preferences and I checked Allow Plugins. I clicked on Plugin settings and selected "on" option too.

P.S:

1. My Java Swing works absolutely well in Applet Viewer. It's just now showing up in a web browser when called through HTML file.
2. java version "1.8.0_91" and HTML5

Any guidance will be appreciated :)

Comment: You don't, and applets are mostly dead in 2017.

Comment: Applets are dead, the plugin is no longer supported by Oracle and most browsers actively block it (and some refuse to install it)

Comment: See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free).